# Changing ringer profile when receiving sms

Tags: android, sms, android-audiomanager

Hello there i'm newbie in Android development
I'm trying to make an app that changes the ringer profile when receive a specific sms, also i can change it by the buttons on the layout (the buttons are working good), but the sms way isn't working

i tried as shown below

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Button Vibrate , Ring , Silent , Mode;
   private TextView Status,sms;
   public static AudioManager myAudioManager;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      Vibrate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      Ring = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
      Silent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
      Mode = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      Status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      sms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sms);

      myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

   }

   public void vibrate(View view){
       myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
   }
   public void ring(View view){
      myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
   }
   public void silent(View view){
      myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
   }
   public void mode(View view){
     int mod = myAudioManager.getRingerMode();
     if(mod == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
         Status.setText("Current Status: Ring");
   }
   else if(mod == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){
       Status.setText("Current Status: Silent");
   }
   else if(mod == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
      Status.setText("Current Status: Vibrate");
   }
   else{

   }
  }
   public static void messageProcessing(String message) {
       if(message=="ring") 
           myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
       else if (message=="vibrate")
           myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
       else if(message=="silent")
           myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

**RecieveSMS.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RecieveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver 
{   
    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
            if (intentExtras != null) {
                Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                    MainActivity.messageProcessing(smsBody);

                    Toast.makeText(context, smsBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:text="@string/audio"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
      android:onClick="silent"
      android:text="@string/Silent" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
      android:onClick="ring"
      android:text="@string/Ring" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:onClick="mode"
      android:text="@string/Mode" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
      android:text="@string/Status"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
       android:onClick="vibrate"
       android:text="@string/Vibrate" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/sms"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
       android:text="@string/Sms"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">Test</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
   <string name="audio">Set Audio Profiles</string>
   <string name="Ring">Ring</string>
   <string name="Vibrate">Vibrate</string>
   <string name="Silent">Silent</string>
   <string name="Mode">Current Mode</string>
   <string name="Status">Current Status</string>
   <string name="Sms">SMS</string>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.test"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
      android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <receiver android:name=".RecieveSMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

any help ??
also , well this app work in background or i should make a service to make that happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out a way to solve my problem and that's how :

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RecieveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver 
{   
    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
            if (intentExtras != null) {
                Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    //Edited from here
                    if (smsBody.contains("silent"))
                    {
                    Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    12345, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    //To here
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context, smsBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }
}
```