# How to temporarily disable notification sound for incoming SMS?

Tags: android, sms

I have implemented `SMS Receiver` that listens for one specific SMS (must contain a keyword). 
I know that since `KitKat` you can't disable the SMS notification, but is it possible to `prevent sound alert/vibration` for this one SMS?

So if user has their phone locked and my SMS comes in, the phone doesn't vibrate or make a sound. But if any other SMS comes in, it works normal.

Comment: No, not unless your app is the default SMS app.

Answer (score 0):

Set reciever priority high, i.e. in `AndroidManifest.xml` set `<intent-filter android:priority="1000">`. You should now be able to call `abortBroadcast();` in `onRecieve()` to avoid it being sent to other listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `abortBroadcast()` is a good idea. It could break other apps that depend on the `Broadcast`. You can just silence the SMS notification sound!

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459976/changing-ringer-profile-when-receiving-sms).